# T-SQL cursor or if or case when

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

`Table_NAME_A`:

```
quotid  itration   QStatus            
--------------------------------
 5329    1           Assigned                                   
 5329    2           Inreview                                   
 5329    3           sold                                           
 4329    1           sold                     
 4329    2           sold                     
 3214    1           assigned                
 3214    2           Inreview
```

Result output should look like this:

```
quotid  itration    QStatus  
------------------------------          
 5329    3           sold                       
 4329    2           sold                     
 3214    2           Inreview
```

T-SQL query, so basically I want the data within "sold" status if not there then "inreview" if not there then "assigned" and also at the same time if "sold" or "inreview" or "assigned" has multiple iteration then i want the highest "iteration".

Please help me, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service; you need to show what you've tried so far and what didn't work.  As it stands, this is just a requirement with no effort shown.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using sql server managment studio so in other words tsql. thanks so much for quick turnaround

Comment: When there's no repetition of `QStatus` per `quotid`, can `Inreview` have higher iteration than `sold`? Can, under the same conditions, `Assigned` have higher iteration than either `sold` or `Inreview`? If the answer is "No" to both questions, then it seems you just want the last iteration per `quotid` (regardless of whether `QStatus` repeats or not). And if that is the real problem, the solution would be much simpler than any of the suggestions you've got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want neither cursors nor if/then for this. Instead, you'll use a series of self-joins to get these results. I'll also use a CTE to simplify getting the max iteration at each step:

```
with StatusIterations As 
(
    SELECT quotID, MAX(itration) Iteration, QStatus
    FROM table_NAME_A
    GROUP BY quotID, QStats
)
select q.quotID, coalesce(sold.Iteration,rev.Iteration,asngd.Iteration) Iteration,
                coalesce(sold.QStatus, rev.QStatus, asngd.QStatus) QStatus 
from
  --initial pass for list of quotes, to ensure every quote is included in the results
  (select distinct quotID from table_NAME_A) q
 --one additional pass for each possible status
left join StatusIterations sold on sold.quotID = q.quotID and sold.QStatus = 'sold'
left join StatusIterations rev on rev.quotID = q.quotID and rev.QStatus = 'Inreview'
left join StatusIterations asngd on asngd.quotID = q.quotID and asngd.QStatus = 'assigned'
```

If you have a table that equates a status with a numeric value, you can further improve on this:

**Table: Status**

```
QStatus   Sequence
'Sold'      3
'Inreview'  2
'Assigned'  1
```

And the code becomes:

```
select t.quotID, MAX(t.itration) itration, t.QStatus
from
(
    select t.quotID, MAX(s.Sequence) As Sequence
    from table_NAME_A t
    inner join Status s on s.QStatus = t.QStatus
    group by t.quotID
) seq
inner join Status s on s.Sequence = seq.Sequence
inner join table_NAME_A t on t.quotID = seq.quotID and t.QStatus = s.QStatus
group by t.quoteID, t.QStatus
```

The above may look like complicated at first, but it can be faster and it will scale easily beyond three statuses without changing the code.

Comment: Hey Coehoorn, this was legit answer and it worked thank you so much, I have been trying since last 2 days and you did it within minutes lol thanks again so much:)

Answer (score 1):

This is a prioritization query.  One way to do this is with successive comparisons in a `union all`:

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where quote_status = 'sold'
union all
select a.*
from table_a a
where quote_status = 'Inreview' and
      not exists (select 1 from table_a a2 where a2.quoteid = a.quoteid and a2.quotestatus = 'sold')
union all
select a.*
from table_a a
where quote_status = 'assigned' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table_a a2
                  where a2.quoteid = a.quoteid and a2.quotestatus in ('sold', 'Inreview')
                 );
```

For performance on a larger set of data, you would want an index on `table_a(quoteid, quotestatus)`.

Comment: Hey Linoff thanks for your quick reply seems like it did work but for me issue still remains with iteration. what if sold has two iteration and i want only the highest iteration and not lower, thanks again for your tremendous help

Comment: Hey its ok if you busy i think the way Mr Coehoorn pointed worked too which is right below yours but thanks again for your help again